# CakePHP : Difference between " $this->fetch('css') & $this->Html->css('cake.generic') in cake php

Tags: css, cakephp-2.3

Can Someone please Explain this two line used in CakePHP layout.ctp file. It seems both line used for adding css .Then what is the difference ? How they works.

```
 $this->Html->css('cake.generic')
 $this->fetch('css')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the documentation on using blocks for [script and CSS files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files).

In your view(s) you can use:
`$this->Html->css('cake.generic')`

In your layout(s), you can use:
`$this->fetch('css')`

> A layout contains presentation code that wraps around a view. Anything
>   you want to see in all of your views should be placed in a layout.

What this means is that when defining your layout, using `$this->fetch('css')` will add in any `css` blocks used in your views, so if in your views you'd put both:

`$this->Html->css('cake.generic')`
`$this->Html->css('cake.special')`

Using `$this->fetch('css')` in your layout would include both. Note that without defining the block content first, it will not call anything. The addition of `$this->Html->css('cake.generic')` in the layout file before the block call ensures it is added if it is not already included in a defined view.